# Save response to object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have page with table and data shows via ng-repeat and ng-model. When I click save button I call `post` service and that posts my data to db and returns me id in callback. How I can save response to my object?

in controller:

```
$scope.saveTask = function (workflow) {
    if (workflow.isSaved == false) {
        workflow.isSaved = true;
        $scope.Task.push($scope.newTask());
        restService.postArbitraryTask(angular.toJson(workflow));
    }
};
```

in rest-service:

```
postArbitraryTask: function (model, callback) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: Global.api.saveArbitraryTask,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: model
    }).success(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (callback) {
            callback(response);
        }
    }).error(function() {});
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `postArbitraryTask` function accepts a callback to which the response will be passed.

Use it:

```
restService.postArbitraryTask(
    angular.toJson(workflow),
    function(response){
        $scope.myObject = response;
    }
);
```

---

Also, instead of:

```
if (workflow.isSaved == false) {
```

You can use:

```
if (!workflow.isSaved) {
```

This behaves basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

your `postArbitraryTask` accepts a callback and passes the response to it

```
postArbitraryTask: function (model, callback) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: Global.api.saveArbitraryTask,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: model
    }).success(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (callback) {
            callback(response);
        }
    }).error(function() {});
},
```

you can modify your saveTask function to use whatever data is returned from the server.

```
$scope.saveTask = function (workflow) {
    if (workflow.isSaved == false) {
        $scope.Task.push($scope.newTask());
        restService.postArbitraryTask(angular.toJson(workflow),
           function(response){
              workflow.isSaved = true;
              workflow.id = response.id;
           }
        );
    }
};
```

you can further modify your code to also handle errors (also success and error are deprecated):

```
postArbitraryTask: function (model, callback) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: Global.api.saveArbitraryTask,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: model
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (callback) {
            callback(false,response);
        }
    },function(response) {
        callback(true,response);
    });
},
```

modify your callback to also accept errors

```
$scope.saveTask = function (workflow) {
    if (workflow.isSaved == false) {
        $scope.Task.push($scope.newTask());
        restService.postArbitraryTask(angular.toJson(workflow),
           function(error,response){
              if(!error){ 
                  workflow.isSaved = true;
                  workflow.id = response.data.id;
              }
              else{
                  //handle error here(display an alert?) if an error occurs or server responds with an error code such as 404 or 500
              }
           }
        );
    }
};
```